# Agricola - After/Also rule

Tags: agricola

For an action space which states:

> After A, also B

such as:

> After Family Growth, also 1 minor Improvement

Does it mean that I **must** do **both Family Growth and Minor Improvement**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**,

The first part is mandatory, the second optional.

The Rules for Family growth [(page 5)](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-agricola-rules-2014.pdf) state:

> Players must have room for offspring in their home before they can
>   use this action  – that is, they must have more rooms in their home than they have Family members. After taking Family growth, the player may choose to purchase a Minor Improvement

Note that in general, a player must be able to use an action to be allowed to place a worker on it. [(page 3)](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-agricola-rules-2014.pdf),

> A Family member may never occupy an Action space without
>   performing its action.

Therefore you cannot place a worker there just to block another player.

Comment: This is a general principle in Agricola, stated on p3 of the rules. You may *not* put a family member token on an action without *taking* that action. When the action says "do X", you *must* do X; when it says "do X or do Y", you *must* do either X or Y (but not both); however, when it says "after X, also Y", you *must* do X, but then you can *choose* to do Y but aren't required to. This principle probably made the action syntax simpler and more concise (for the purposes of printing on cards), but it also lead to a bit of incongruity in the syntax.

Comment: @ViktorHaag - Note: I'm pretty certain that you're allowed to put a token on any space, including a 'after/also' space, and simply not perform the first action (and not perform any action at all). For example if you wanted to prevent your opponent from taking that space.

Comment: @dwjohnston - updated my answer with the full rules quotes.

Comment: @PatLudwig Huh, TIL.